# Change sweetalert placeholder color with css

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert

I have a [Sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) as follows:

```
swal({
                                               title: "my title",
                                               text: "",
                                               type: "input",
                                               imageUrl: "images/my_image.png",
                                               showCancelButton: true,
                                               closeOnConfirm: false,
                                               animation: "slide-from-top",
                                               inputPlaceholder: "username..."
                                               },
                                               function(inputValue){
                                               if (inputValue === false) return false;
                                               if (inputValue === "") {
                                               swal.showInputError("you didn't type anything...");
                                               return false
                                               }
                                               });
```

How can I change the color of the **inputPlaceholder** that appears in the sweetalert. I have tried:

```
.sweet-alert input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.sweet-alert input::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.sweet-alert input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.sweet-alert input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.inputPlaceholder {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried your css on the website's prompt demo and it works. https://s30.postimg.org/gvd76vs35/Screen_Shot_2017_01_14_at_1_48_20_AM.png

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In sweetalert.css file there are these lines related to the placehodler:

```
.sweet-alert input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
        transition: opacity 0.3s 0.03s ease;
        opacity: 0.9; }
      .sweet-alert input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
        transition: opacity 0.3s 0.03s ease;
        opacity: 0.9; }
      .sweet-alert input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        transition: opacity 0.3s 0.03s ease;
        opacity: 0.9; }
    .sweet-alert input::-moz-placeholder {
      color: whitesmoke; }
    .sweet-alert input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: whitesmoke; }
    .sweet-alert input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: whitesmoke; }
```

Just had to change the opacities and the colors.