# Sweetalert 2 placeholder opacity

Tags: html, css, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I've created a form with sweetalert2 but the placeholder is barely visible. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644424/change-sweetalert-placeholder-color-with-css) post about sweetalert placeholder styling. But this is for sweetalert. I've looked at my code if perhaps the same worked for 2.

I've found this code in **sweetalert2.css**

```
.swal2-modal .swal2-input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-file:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  opacity: .8;
}

.swal2-modal .swal2-input:focus::-moz-placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-file:focus::-moz-placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  opacity: .8;
}

.swal2-modal .swal2-input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-file:focus:-ms-input-placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  opacity: .8;
}

.swal2-modal .swal2-input:focus::placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-file:focus::placeholder,
.swal2-modal .swal2-textarea:focus::placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s .03s ease;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

But when I change the opacity and refresh my page nothing different is happening. And I cant seem to figure out where in the browser (Inspect element) I can find the specific CSS (because its a placeholder).

Answer (score 4):

There's the `inputClass` option which you can use for amending the default input styling:

```js
swal({
  title: 'Input with custom styling',
  input: 'text',
  inputPlaceholder: 'Placeholder text',
  inputClass: 'custom-input-class'
 })
```

```css
.custom-input-class::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #f00 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

Read more about available options here: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Comment: I have the swal set as *html* because I have multiple inputs. 
If I set it like this :           ` html:
 '<h2>Login details</h2>'+
 '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" autofocus placeholder="Username">' +
 '<input type="password" id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Password">',
',`
It doesn't seem to work..